# Understanding Pandas SettingWithCopyWarning

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I have the following code but don't quite understand why it is throwing the warning.  I have read the [documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy) but still cannot wrap my head around why this usage would result in the warning.  Any insight would be appreciated.

```
>>> df = pandas.DataFrame({'a': [1,2,3,4,5,6,7], 'b': [11,22,33,44,55,66,77]})
>>> reduced_df = df[df['a'] > 3]
>>> reduced_df
   a   b
3  4  44
4  5  55
5  6  66
6  7  77
>>> reduced_df['a'] /= 3

Warning (from warnings module):
   File "__main__", line 1
SettingWithCopyWarning: A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_index,col_indexer] = value instead
>>> reduced_df
          a   b
3  1.333333  44
4  1.666667  55
5  2.000000  66
6  2.333333  77
```

Comment: This line `reduced_df = df[df['a'] > 3]` means `reduced_df` is a copy of the slice from `df`, you are now trying to assign some value on this hence the warning. You can take an explicit copy like so: `reduced_df = df[df['a'] > 3].copy()` or if you wanted to modify the original df then `df.loc[df['a']>3,'a'] = df['a']/3`

Comment: I guess the reason the warning exists is that typically you expect in python that `foo = bar` will mean that `foo` is a reference to `bar` so if you modify `foo` then you expect `bar` to change which isn't the case here

Comment: So the warning is telling me that any changes I make to reduced_df will not show up in df because the `reduced_df = df[df['a'] > 3]` line produces a deep copy?

Comment: yes, but because you've not been explicit here it's warning you what will happen, like I said if you did `reduced_df = df[df['a'] >3].copy()` then there is no warning as you have now explicitly taken a deep copy

Comment: Excellent - the fact that it was making a deep copy is what I was not getting.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The warning here is to tell you that your `reduced_df` despite appearances is not a reference to a slice of your `df` but in fact a copy. This is different to the normal semantics where one would expect this to result in a reference and that modifications to that reference will affect the reference and the original object (for mutable objects of course):

```
In [14]:

foo = [0]
bar = foo
bar.append(1)
print(foo,bar)
[0, 1] [0, 1]
```

So if you wanted to modify a particular slice of your df then you should do what the warning suggests:

```
In [18]:

df.loc[df['a']>3,'a'] =df['a']/3
df
Out[18]:
          a   b
0  1.000000  11
1  2.000000  22
2  3.000000  33
3  1.333333  44
4  1.666667  55
5  2.000000  66
6  2.333333  77
```

Or make an explicit deep copy calling `copy()` and modify the copy without any warning generated:

```
In [20]:

reduced_df = df[df['a'] > 3].copy()
reduced_df['a'] /=3
reduced_df
Out[20]:
          a   b
3  1.333333  44
4  1.666667  55
5  2.000000  66
6  2.333333  77

In [21]:
# orig df is unmodified
df
Out[21]:
   a   b
0  1  11
1  2  22
2  3  33
3  4  44
4  5  55
5  6  66
6  7  77
```