# understanding pandas slicing copy SettingWithCopyWarning:

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, copy, slice

I try to understand how pandas works on slicing and copy, when I try to run the code below, it appears 'SettingWithCopyWarning'. How to account for this ?

There are references here ([Understanding Pandas SettingWithCopyWarning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26536327/understanding-pandas-settingwithcopywarning)) but I still don't understand how it works, any other references?

```
test1 = pd.DataFrame(index = [1,2,3,4,5])
test1['a'] = [11,12,13,14,15]
test1['b'] = ''
test1['b'].iloc[0] = test1['a'].iloc[0]
test1
```

Comment: Please read this question on [copy vs view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23296282/what-rules-does-pandas-use-to-generate-a-view-vs-a-copy).

Comment: Thanks mozway.. for your reference